# Linq-to-SQL query returns error "Invalid Cast"

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

Here's my code that returns a list of articles and display them in a listbox. The strange thing is that it is working fine in Visual Studio 2019, but returns an error

> Invalid cast

in Visual Studio 2017 !

The error happens at the line `ArtListBox.Itemssource...`

```
private void GetArticles()
{
    DataClasses1DataContext dc = new DataClasses1DataContext();

    IOrderedQueryable<FICHES_ARTICLES> art = (from a in dc.PESEES
                                              join p in dc.FICHES_ARTICLES on a.ART_CODE equals p.ART_CODE
                                              where a.PESEE_ST == 0
                                              select p).Distinct().OrderBy(x => x.ART_LIBELLE1);

    ArtListBox.ItemsSource = art;
    ArtListBox.DisplayMemberPath = "ART_LIBELLE1";
    ArtListBox.SelectedValuePath = "ART_CODE";
}
```

Can someone help me fix this error? I would really appreciate it.

Comment: I believe `.ToList()` will work for you.. What is type of `ArtListBox.ItemsSource `

Comment: It is type of string

Comment: I guess it should be of type `List<string>`, if it is string then you need to assign string value to `ArtListBox.ItemsSource` not a `IOrderedQueryable<FICHES_ARTICLES>`. What is type of `FICHES_ARTICLES`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your comment `ArtListBox.ItemsSource` is of type `string` so you need to assign string value to `ItemsSource` property

```
IOrderedQueryable<FICHES_ARTICLES> art = (from a in dc.PESEES
                                              join p in dc.FICHES_ARTICLES on a.ART_CODE equals p.ART_CODE
                                              where a.PESEE_ST == 0
                                              select p).Distinct().OrderBy(x => x.ART_LIBELLE1);
ArtListBox.ItemsSource = art.FirstOrDefault();
```

> `FirstOrDefault()` will return first element of sequence which
>   stratify `a.PESEE_ST == 0`, or a default value if no element found.